# Solve unable to provide the full solution

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r \[Element] Reals, r >= 0, rh \[Element] Reals, 
   rh > 0};
S[rh_] := \[Pi] rh^2
M[rh_, qe_, qm_] := 
 1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/S[rh]] (S[rh]^2/\[Pi]^2 + S[rh]/\[Pi]  + qe^2 + qm^2)
qe = SolveValues[\[Phi]e == qe (1/rh - 1/r), qe];
f[r_, rh_, qm_, \[Phi]e_] := 
 1 + r^2/l^2 - (2 M[rh, qe, qm])/r + (qe^2 + qm^2)/r^2
G[rh_, qm_, \[Phi]e_] := 
 1/(4 \[Pi]^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]/
  S[rh]] (3 \[Pi]^2 qm^2 - S[rh]^2 + \[Pi] S[rh] (1 - \[Phi]e^2))
T[rh_, qm_, \[Phi]e_] := (-\[Pi]^2 qm^2 + 
   3 S[rh]^2 + \[Pi] (S[rh] - S[rh] \[Phi]e^2))/(4 (\[Pi] S[rh])^(3/2))

Veff[r_] := f[r, rh, qm, \[Phi]e] (L^2/r^2 + 1);

eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 D[f[r0, rh, qm, \[Phi]e], 
        r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, qm, \[Phi]e] - 
       r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, \[Phi]e], r0]) /. r -> r0 // Simplify

sol = Block[{l = 1, L = 20, \[Phi]e = 0.6}, Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]]

l = 1; L = 20; \[Phi]e = 0.6;

\[Lambda][rh_, qm_, \[Phi]e_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[(r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, \[Phi]e], r0] - 
          2 f[r0, rh, qm, \[Phi]e]) Veff''[r0]] /. r -> r0 /. 
    sol[[5]] // Simplify;

pplt1 = ParametricPlot[{T[rh, 0.05, \[Phi]e], \[Lambda][rh, 
    0.05, \[Phi]e]}, {rh, 0.01, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.4}, {0, 2}},
   AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

which gives me the following plot as the output:

[image: fig2]

while the desired plot should look similar to this:

[image: fig1]

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact values and intermediate simplification

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, rh > 0};

S[rh_] := π rh^2
M[rh_, qe_, qm_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[π/S[rh]] (S[rh]^2/π^2 + S[rh]/π + qe^2 + qm^2) // Simplify;

qe = SolveValues[ϕe == q (1/rh - 1/r), q][[1]] // Simplify;

f[r_, rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1 + r^2/l^2 - (2 M[rh, qe, qm])/r + (qe^2 + qm^2)/r^2 // Simplify;

G[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1/(4 π^2) Sqrt[π/S[rh]] (3 π^2 qm^2 - 
      S[rh]^2 + π S[rh] (1 - ϕe^2)) // Simplify;

T[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = (-π^2 qm^2 + 
      3 S[rh]^2 + π (S[rh] - S[rh] ϕe^2))/(4 (π S[rh])^(3/2)) // 
   Simplify;

Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, qm, ϕe] (L^2/r^2 + 1) // FullSimplify;

eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe] - 
        r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0]) /. r -> r0 // FullSimplify;

sol = Block[{l = 1, L = 20, ϕe = 3/5}, Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]];

l = 1; L = 20; ϕe = 3/5;

λ[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[(r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0] - 2 f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe]) *
   Veff''[r0]] /. r -> r0 /. sol // Simplify;

Off[General::munfl, Less::nord]
```

Include two branches

```
pplt1 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{T[rh, 1/20, ϕe], #} & /@ (λ[rh, 1/20, ϕe][[{3, 5}]])],
  {rh, 1/100, 2},
  PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.4}, {0, 3.5}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.5,
  Exclusions -> All]
```

[image]