# How to combine multiple plots via Table when a map is being applied?

Tags: plotting, functions, map, table

This question is based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284651/78049)

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, rh > 0};

S[rh_] := π rh^2
M[rh_, qe_, qm_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[π/S[rh]] (S[rh]^2/π^2 + S[rh]/π + qe^2 + qm^2) // Simplify;

qe = SolveValues[ϕe == q (1/rh - 1/r), q][[1]] // Simplify;

f[r_, rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1 + r^2/l^2 - (2 M[rh, qe, qm])/r + (qe^2 + qm^2)/r^2 // Simplify;

G[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1/(4 π^2) Sqrt[π/S[rh]] (3 π^2 qm^2 - 
      S[rh]^2 + π S[rh] (1 - ϕe^2)) // Simplify;

T[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = (-π^2 qm^2 + 
      3 S[rh]^2 + π (S[rh] - S[rh] ϕe^2))/(4 (π S[rh])^(3/2)) // 
   Simplify;

Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, qm, ϕe] (L^2/r^2 + 1) // FullSimplify;

eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe] - 
        r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0]) /. r -> r0 // FullSimplify;

sol = Block[{l = 1, L = 20, ϕe = 3/5}, Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]];

l = 1; L = 20; ϕe = 3/5;

λ[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[(r0 D[f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe], r0] - 2 f[r0, rh, qm, ϕe]) *
   Veff''[r0]] /. r -> r0 /. sol // Simplify;

Off[General::munfl, Less::nord]
```

which I tried to generalize for multiple values of `qm` by using the standard method of creating a Table before plotting:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[{T[rh, qm, ϕe], #} & /@ (λ[rh, 
       qm, ϕe][[{3, 5}]]), {qm, 0.04, 0.12, 0.02}], {rh, 0.01, 
  8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0.1, 4.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 Exclusions -> All]
```

but unfortunately, it gives me a blank plot. Probably my use of a `Table` is erroneous when a map is being applied. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Comment: Please share the definition of `T` and other parameters, so we can run the code. It may also help if you remove the formatting niceties if they are not relevant to the problem. They just clutter the code up and may mask an otherwise obvious issue.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the useful suggestions. I have edited my question keeping those in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definitions from your earlier question.

[`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) the output of your [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

[`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) of `300` is excessive (unnecessary slows down the plot); just use the default.

Including `qm =` for each legend entry just adds clutter. I recommend that you use [`LegendLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLabel.html).

There are two entries for each value of `qm` so the colors don't align with the values. Manually set the colors in the legend. (I added [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) to aid in this process)

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
  Flatten[
   Table[
    Tooltip[{T[rh, qm, ϕe], #}, StringForm["qm = ``", qm]] & /@
     (λ[rh, qm, ϕe][[{3, 5}]]),
    {qm, 0.04, 0.12, 0.02}],
   1],
 {rh, 0.01, 8},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0.1, 4.5}},
 AspectRatio -> 0.5,
 Exclusions -> All,
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "NeonColor"},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperature \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31],
   Style["Lyapunov Exponent \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[
    {RGBColor[1., 0.4, 0.], RGBColor[0., 0.742291, 0.873126], 
     RGBColor[0.893126, 0.4, 0.767184], RGBColor[
     0.238758, 0.610466, 1.], RGBColor[0.295048, 0.8, 0.286932]},
    Range[0.04, 0.12, 0.02],
    LegendLabel -> Style["qm", 14]],
   {0.95, 0.8}],
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: The line through the plot is an artifact of the copy and paste. The `ImageSize` is larger than my laptop could display and produces the artifact.

Comment: Thank you so much again!